# Filtering Data in CSV file

Tags: regex, linux, csv, awk, sed

I have CSV file in this format

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,no disk detected
a,b,c,d,e,f,disk run into error
a,b,c,d,e,f,no memory in the server
a,b,c,d,e,f,memory has correctable errors
```

in the last column, I need to search for the word

disk and replace it with  disk error
memory and replace it with a memory error
That part I already figure out

```
 cat filename.csv |awk -F "," '{print $NF}' |sed 's/^.*disk.*$/disk error/'  |sed 's/^.*memory.*$/memory error/'
```

Now the part I need help to when sed replace this string, can it's possible to write into the same file(filename.csv) or generate a new file with all columns + updated column, so new file will look like this

```
 a,b,c,d,e,f,disk error
 a,b,c,d,e,f,disk error
 a,b,c,d,e,f,memory error
 a,b,c,d,e,f,memory error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to do with `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(.+,).*(disk|memory).*$/\1\2 error/' file.csv
```

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,disk error
a,b,c,d,e,f,disk error
a,b,c,d,e,f,memory error
a,b,c,d,e,f,memory error
```

To make changes inline in same file use:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/^(.+,).*(disk|memory).*$/\1\2 error/' file.csv
```

**== Details ==**

**Search Regex:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.+,)`: **Greedy Match** till last comma and capture it in group #1
- `.*(disk|memory)`: Match 0 or more characters before matching `disk` or `memory` and capture it in group #2
- `.*$`: Match 0 or more characters before end

**Replacement Pattern:**

- `\1`: Back-reference to group #1 to place text till last comma back
- `\2 error`: Append `disk error` or `memory error`

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, '{if ($NF~/disk/) $NF="disk error"; if ($NF~/memory/) $NF="memory error";}1' OFS=, file
```

With GNU awk v4.1.0+, you can add `-i inplace` switch to change the `file` inplace.
Otherwise, try `awk .... file | tee file`.

So above command itself does not require GNU awk, but if you have GNU awk, you can do it with this more concise way:

```
awk -F, '{match($NF,"(disk|memory)",m);$NF=m[1] " error";}1' OFS=, file
```

`NF` means column number, `$NF` means the last column.
`-F,` set the `FS` field separator to comma.
`OFS=,` set the outout field separator to comma.

Comment: We can do without the very last semicolon.

Comment: @ClaesWikner Yep, it can be saved. Thanks for mention it. I added it here is to have some kind of *closure*, just feeling better :)